# how to receive data from different datasources and transmit them through JMS

Tags: jpa, jms

The project is required to receive lot of data(the possible historical weather data of one State) from different datasources, like zip files, data files within a website. The data format is not clear, the files might be txt, pdf, or .xml.

Since it specifies that JMS and JPA should be used for implementation, I am thinking use JMS ObjectMessage to transfer data to application server. The advantage of Obejct Message is that it can read data as an object and so I can store them as persistent object in memory. And use JPA access them for lata query.

I am looking for a simple and extendable way to do this with JMS and JPA. The data source, data format, data size might change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Create a client (a sample test class) which will read data from the FSL/INGRA file and create text JMS messages and send them to your server.